# VLC Player Mac View Playlist Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

In VLC PLayer for Windows and Linux when playing a video file I can click a button or press `CTRL + L` to "hide" the video and view the playlist/library, handy for (pseudo) music videos.

https://www.vlchelp.com/access-manage-use-playlist/

In the view menu there is an option which shows the shortcut, this is not the case on macOS. Control and L do nothing, `⌘+L` is for repeat all.

## VLC Windows View Playlist Screenshot:

[image]

## VLC Player macOS View Menu Screenshot:

[image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this on macOS?

Comment: According to [52 Shortcuts for VLC Media Player (MacOS)](https://shortcutworld.com/VLC-Media-Player/mac/VLC-Media-Player_Shortcuts#Manage_VLC,_Playlists,_and_Special_Commands) there isn't one ...

Comment: That page says macOS but lists CTRL instead of ⌘ as the modifier key?

Comment: cmd+option+p shows/hides playlist, it is in the windows menu not the view menu - doesn't work in full screen - using vlc Version 3.0.11 Vetinari (Intel 64bit) for MacOS.

Comment: Thank you!!! I looked in the Window menu but must have not noticed it because it doesn't say view playlist.

Comment: Zina  Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Otherwise I will have to answer and accept my own answer, but I don't want to do that, you deserve the credit for that useful information!!!

Comment: I upvoted but it's not applied because I have less than 15 reputation as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS VLC Version 3.0.11 (where the screenshot is taken from):

[image: Show / hide Playlist]

**option + cmd + p** => shows/hides playlist, it is in the Window menu - with the note that doesn't work in full screen.